# Slide From Left Pushing everything to the next row

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slidetoggle

I have a slide in from left effect on some elements that are put on screen at a regular interval.  The idea is that each of these elements is floated left so it appears a stream going from left to right.

The problem is that the slide from left effect pushes everything to the row beneath it until it has finished the animation.  It was working fine when the transition was a fade in.  [Here is a link](http://high-fog-8435.herokuapp.com/) to the test page.  Just click on 'Pinterest' on the landing page and you'll be able to see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw thew animation uses a temporal element with a class named `.ui-effects-wrapper`, but this class is not defined in any CSS file. At the same time, the temporal element uses inline styles. In theses I found a `Float: none` style, which is why the the animation pushes everthing beneath it.

So, to solve the problem; declare, in your CSS file a class named `.ui-effects-wrapper` with a `float: left` rule.

```
.ui-effects-wrapper {
    float: left !important
}
```

`!important` prevents inlines styles to override `.ui-effects-wrapper` defined rules. That solves the problem. Just as a comment, I noticed the animation was not smooth after many pictures where fetched.